# Sending email fails

Tags: laravel

I am using my Gmail account and smtp.gmail.com inside my web application(laravel) to test and send the reset password email. When I click on the button "send password reset link", the laravel gave me the error:

> "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxemail@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials hj15-20020a056870c90f00b001631c5f7404sm2432098oab.22 - gsmtp".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials hj15-20020a056870c90f00b001631c5f7404sm2432098oab.22 - gsmtp".". Authenticator "XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "334", with message "334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ=="."."

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail9@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

What can I do to solve this problem?
I had tried to change the e-mail, but not success.
I AM ALREADY USING THE "APP PASSWORD"!

Comment: "Username and Password not accepted" seems pretty clear. Read the linked doc; you'll need the "App Password" (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) bit.

Comment: I'm already using the app password! –

Answer (score 1):

I remember falling in this mistake in the past, in google there's feature called "App Password"

ref: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

So instead of directly using your email and password you have to create new App password and use it, my advice tho (and it's google's advice) is that app password is kinda risky.

Comment: I'm already using the app password!